# Application crashes after running for a while

Tags: android

This is the entire code running. It runs for some while and runs fine but then crashes suddenly. I can't find the problem. Can anyone help, please? It is the first ever app i made. All the help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
public void onPostExecute (String result) {
   if (result.indexOf("#") == -1){MessageAvCheck = false;}
   else if (result.indexOf("#") >= 0)
   {
     mtake = result.split("#");
     final Runnable run = new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            StringTokenizer bits = new StringTokenizer(mtake[x], "$");
            String mNumber = bits.nextToken();
            mphone = bits.nextToken();
            mmessage = bits.nextToken();
            mphone = mdial.concat(mphone);
            SendingMessage.setText(mmessage);
            MessageAvCheck = true;

            StringTokenizer dt = new StringTokenizer (msDate, " ");
            mFile = dt.nextToken();
            SendingTime = dt.nextToken();
            mFile = mFile.replace("/", "");
            SendingTime = SendingTime.replace(":", "");
            SendingTime = mFile.concat(SendingTime);
         };
         if (x == 0){loop.post(run);
     }
 }
```

This is what logCat gives at the time the app crashes.

```
06-01 20:33:20.253: W/dalvikvm(7314): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d599a8)
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314):     at pk.albab.SMSserver.MainActivity$DownloadWebPageTask$1.run(MainActivity.java:101)
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-01 20:33:20.257: E/AndroidRuntime(7314):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i don't know that. Am i count it? I don't know where it is displayed, otherwise.

Comment: Your IDE should display the line numbers for you. If they are not shown on every line then check for a status bar at the bottom which would show the currently selected line number.

Comment: StringTokenizer bits = new StringTokenizer(mtake[x], "$"); This appears to be the line 101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to access a second element of the String array `mtake` when only 1 element exists.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

When you assign `mtake` from `result` only one element is returned from the `split()`. Since you do test for the existence of a '#' char I would say that it is found but at the end of the String. I'll attach a test at the end to show how `split()` works in different situations.

You need to look at your `result` before continuing on the assumption that the `split()` succeeded the way you expected it to and address the possible issues by any one of:

- test for the length of the `split()`
- use a `for...each` loop
- catch the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` thrown

---

Here's a test to show how `split()` can work with **found characters** at different positions:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] strings = {
            "no char here",
            "in the # middle",
            "# was at start",
            "now at the end #"
    };

    for (String str : strings)
    {
        String[] parts = str.split("#");
        System.out.println("'" + str + "', split into: " + parts.length);
        for (String s : parts)
        {
            System.out.println("\t '" + s + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
'no char here', split into: 1
     'no char here'
'in the # middle', split into: 2
     'in the '
     ' middle'
'# was at start', split into: 2
     ''
     ' was at start'
'at the end #', split into: 1
     'now at the end '
```

As you can see the last case has the '#' character but `split()` only returns an array of length 1.

Comment: i have a check that it will go the runnable if and only if it finds the  #  not otherwise. It doesn't work that way?

Comment: plus, it runs quite fine for a long while and crashes after that.

Comment: Thank you. That helped! Thank you very much!!! I can't vote it up with the current reputation or i would definitely have!

Comment: You're welcome. As a side note you should look at tidying up your code and splitting it into multiple methods instead of the currently very lengthy few that you now have. Use descriptive variable and method names and it will make your code a lot easier to follow, debug and read.

Comment: Thank you! I would keep that in my mind. I used the lengthy method as i don't understand the scope much. Dunno why but can't access the mtake outside the onPostExecute() even though it is globally declared

Comment: That issue would require a new question to help you with. Feel free to make one but I'd suggest you read up on variable scope first and come back if you can't figure it out.